# asyncio: cancel read() task after interval of silence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Context, in a nutshell: A program I *can't* control feeds data to mine through sys.stdin, but for some reason it lies about the content-length. (For example: it says I should expect 11 characters, but then only sends 10, so my `sys.stdin.read(11)` hangs forever. I have no way of knowing what the actual content-length is going to be, so I want to make a listener that can tell when the input has stopped based on time rather than content. I'm trying to work with Python's asyncio for the first time, here's my sample code to reproduce my dilemma. I need to be able to cancel a sys.stdin.read(1) operation after I get nothing for a certain amount of time:

```
import time
import sys
import asyncio

IMPATIENCE = 0.1  # how often to check out updates
PATIENCE = 5.0    # how long since latest update before throwing a fit


async def chars_to_line(ifile, ofile, checkin):
    line = ''
    while True:
        print(' ', end='')
        char = ifile.read(1)
        if char:
            if char != '\n':
                line += char
            else:
                checkin['last'] = checkin['latest']
                checkin['latest'] = time.time()
                ofile.write(line + char)
                ofile.flush()
                line = ''


async def impatient(checkout, i, o):
    task = asyncio.create_task(chars_to_line(i, o, checkout))
    while True:
        print('.', end='')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        print(checkout['latest'] - time.time())
        if checkout['latest'] - time.time() >= 5.0:
            print('Done waiting!')
            task.cancel()
            await task
            break
        else:
            print('still waiting...')

status = {'last': time.time(), 'latest': time.time()}
asyncio.run(impatient(status, sys.stdin, sys.stdout))
```

I only arrived at asyncio because threading doesn't allow me to abort a thread from the outside and multiprocessing needs an `if __name__ == '__main__'` wrapper for Windows (which for various reasons is not going to be an option for this project). `concurrent.futures` had the same problem as multiprocessing, so I'm running out of options here. If asyncio can't abort a frozen task either then I'll have to make something ugly and inflated with subprocess, which I'd like to avoid.

Thanks!

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` is a blocking call and therefore not allowed in an async function. `chars_to_line` is defined as async, but doesn't await anything and it contains a blocking call which will block the whole event loop. This is why your attempt at cancellation doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @user4815162342! I did read that each task has to yield control back to the event loop, but then I read about the ```task.cancel()``` method being used to raise a ```asyncio.CancelledError``` and had hoped that meant it could interrupt blocking tasks. I really got my hopes up too... such is the life of coding. On to the next option!